# connection ToggleButtonBar, combobox and datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, combobox, flash-builder, togglebutton

I want to connect these 3 together.  When you choose from the togglebutton bar it will be displayed in the combobox, and from there you can choose other data that will be displayed in the datagrid.

Now I have the first two connected:

```
private function toggle(event:ItemClickEvent):void{

                list2.selectedIndex=-1; // reset so prompt shows
                if (togglebtn.selectedIndex==0)
                list2.dataProvider=elecItems;
                else if(togglebtn.selectedIndex==1)
                list2.dataProvider=toyItems;

            }

<mx:ToggleButtonBar id="togglebtn" x="9" y="29" color="0x323232" dataProvider="{dp}" horizontalGap="4" itemClick="toggle(event)"/>

<s:ComboBox id="list2" x="159" y="28" width="549" itemClick="select_item(event)"/>
```

now I want to connect the combobox with the datagrid, but when I use:

```
if (list2.selectedIndex==0)
info_dg.dataProvider={info};
```

it directs to two indexes.... anyway I don7t quite understand it myself and hope to get some help.

also instead of using SelectedIndex==0 could I use an ID instead?

Data structure:
ToggleButtonBar

```
[Bindable]public var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {label:"商品", data:399}, 
            {label:"顧客", data:599}]);
```

Combobox

```
[Bindable]public var elecItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {label:"text", data:299}, 
                {label:"tttナビ", data:999}, 
                {label:"大学院ttt", data:999}, 
                {label:"ttt", data:999}, 
                {label:"ttt制作", data:899},
                {label:"tttt", data:899}]);


            [Bindable]public var toyItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {label:"text", data:120}, 
                {label:"text", data:50}, 
                {label:"text", data:50},
                {label:"(株)text", data:30} ]);
```

Datagrid XML file:

```
<fx:XMLList id="Info">
            <employee>
                <name>eeee／完了</name>
                <phone>eee</phone>
                <email>eee制作</email>
                <active>300,000</active>
                <image>eeee</image>
            </employee>
            <employee>
                <name>rrr／完了</name>
                <phone>rrr</phone>
                <email>rrr設営</email>
                <active>1,900,000</active>
                <image>rrrしないように</image>
            </employee>
        </fx:XMLList>
```

Comment: Could you show your data structures please? It would help me to offer you a solution.

Comment: I have tried to run your programm after some correction. It works. What is meant by "it directs to two indexes"?

Comment: because there are two options on the first togglebar you would have 2 selectedIndex==0 on the list... or do I see this wrong?  how do they connect with each other.   I'm glad to hear you could make it work, but I would like to know how as well haha

Comment: We should discuss the process once more. If I push one of the buttons, it affects which list is used as a source of the combobox. Right? Suppose I have pressed the second button. So we use toyItems. Now I select one item from the combobox. Which options do I have to determin the content of the datagrid? How many possible sources for the datagrid do you have? I see only <fx:XMLList id="Info">. Do you have more?

Comment: yeah I will have a list for all items in both of the two combolists... although it might be easier to put everything together in one XML file... not sure what would be better

Comment: and what about datagrids? Do you have a list of workers for each combination of toggle index and combobox index?

Comment: if you have a separate list of employee for each option, use this expression info_dg.dataProvider = info[togglebtn.selectedIndex].group[list2.selectedIndex].employee;

Comment: thanks, it's getting a bit clearer but what does group stands for? I have this now... 

protected function changedatagridfromcombo(event:MouseEvent):void
   {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (list2.selectedIndex==0)
     info_dg.dataProvider = Info[togglebtn.selectedIndex].group[list2.selectedIndex].employee; 
    else if(togglebtn.selectedIndex==1)
     info_dg.dataProvider = Info2[togglebtn.selectedIndex].group[list2.selectedIndex].employee;     
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have such a structure to save informations about employees

```
<fx:XMLList id="info">
        <toggle>
            <group>
                <employee>
                    <name>ei1_name1</name>
                    <phone>phone1</phone>
                </employee>
                <employee>
                    <name>ei1_name2</name>
                    <phone>phone2</phone>
                </employee>
            </group>
            <group>
                <employee>
                    <name>ei2_name1</name>
                    <phone>phone1</phone>
                </employee>
                <employee>
                    <name>ei2_name2</name>
                    <phone>phone2</phone>
                </employee>
            </group>
        </toggle>

        <toggle>
            <group>
                <employee>
                    <name>ti1_name1</name>
                    <phone>phone1</phone>
                </employee>
                <employee>
                    <name>ti1_name2</name>
                    <phone>phone2</phone>
                </employee>
            </group>
            <group>
                <employee>
                    <name>ti2_name1</name>
                    <phone>phone1</phone>
                </employee>
                <employee>
                    <name>ti2_name2</name>
                    <phone>phone2</phone>
                </employee>
            </group>
        </toggle>

    </fx:XMLList>
```

There are two toggle blocks to tell "toy" and "elec" apart.
Each block has a number of "group" items - each for the corresponding item in the CheckBox.

If it is ok, then you should not use any "if else". Instead of it your function would look like

```
        private function onCbChanged(evt:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            info_dg.dataProvider = info[togglebtn.selectedIndex].group[list2.selectedIndex].employee;
        }
```

The "togglebtn.selectedIndex" selects a toggle block and the "list2.selectedIndex" selects a group of the toggle.